# asp.net insert query with to_date function

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g

I am inserting record in db using below mentioned query but it gives me error "Invalid number" so guide me.

```
 string query1 = "insert into MNE.MNE_users(USER_ID,INSERTED_DATE) values ( '" + id + "',to_date('" + INSERTED_DATE.Text + "','DD/MM/YYYY')   )";
```

Please guide me.

Comment: `" + IS_ACTIVE + "'` should be `"' + IS_ACTIVE + "'`, check your query string again as this issue occurs more than once. This is a proofreading task that doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow, you should be more than capable of doing this yourself instead of relying on others to clean up your code.

Comment: NOT working I added all the comma missing giving error quoted string not properly ended. I also updated my query. Please see updated query.

Comment: Then start over again and build the query one value at a time, make sure the number of fields you are defining in the `INTO` section match the number of fields defined in the `VALUES` section.

Comment: I did it thousand of time and it is inserting record without to date function. when i use to date function it gives me above mentioned error

Comment: I updated the above question. now giving me error invalid number

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html). **NEVER** use string concatenation to build a SQL query. **ALWAYS** use a parameterized query.

Answer (score 1):

```
to_date() function solves my Problem
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace; 'yyyy-mm-dd + ' with 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: add comma between + FLEX1 + MONITOR_NAME +

Comment: I updated the above question. now giving me error invalid number